# Dynamics 365 OnPremise + VPN = CI/CD process within AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, dynamics-crm, vpn, azure-devops-server

welcome community.

currently, our customer has Dynamics 365 On-premise infrastructure, additionally more connected applications to CRM. All is available thru VPN.

Case is to implement CI/CD process. i would like to use AzureDevOps Cloud.
Code management solutions = bitbucket.
Of course its not a problem to implement full ci/cd process within OnPremise Dynamics but the question is HOW we manage to bypass VPN?

i have found some tips in MS documentation with Agents and more but i am not sure if this will work.
any suggestion? thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you are using Dynamics 365 On-premise. You will need to configure self-hosted agents on your local machine. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps.

Since D365 is behind a proxy. You will need to configure your self-hosted agent to run behind a web proxy. See detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows).

[image]

There is no need to install Azure devops server. You just need to configure your azure pipeline to run on your self-hosted agent created in above steps. So that your azure pipeline can access to the on-premise resources.

When you configure your pipeline(see below for more information about configure pipeline), Choose the Agent pool(`Default` for below example) where the self-hosted agent resides to run your pipeline on your self-hosted agent.

[image]

[image]

You need to create azure pipeline for CI/CD process within azure devops.

Below are the examples in detailed steps to configure a classic pipeline in azure devops to implement CI/CD for Dynamics 365.

1, [CI/CD for Dynamics 365 CE using Azure DevOps](https://ssharmacrm.wordpress.com/2020/06/21/ci-cd-for-dynamics-365-ce-using-azure-devops/)

2, [Build Azure DevOps Pipelines for Dynamics 365 CRM/Power Platform](https://pooja-bhardwaj.medium.com/automate-solution-deployment-for-dynamics-365-power-platform-using-azure-pipelines-part-1-df547c4695a4)

If you are to configure release pipeline for CD process. You probably will need to create [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) to deploy to on-premise D365.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=azure-devops) to provision agents to deployment groups.

3, Check [D365 forum](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/305090/dynamics-365-devops-supported-by-microsoft) for more threads about integration D365 with azure devops.

You will much likely encounter some problems while configuring azure pipeline. Please raise new threads about each specific problem your encountered in configuring azure pipeline.

Comment: thanks yor tips. So self hosted agent can be configured in a way that will bypass VPN, am i right?

Comment: Hi @TomaszFałdrowicz If you found above answer is helpful. Could you [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks!

Comment: answer is helpful - i can tick it as an aswer - when last question will be answered.  This is regarding VPN connection.

Comment: Hi @TomaszFałdrowicz Configuring your self-hosted agent to [run behind a web proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) will help bypass VPN.

Comment: Thank you. So Self Hosted Agent can also help with Bitbucket Server (previously i mentioned Cloud - mistake), correct?

Comment: Hi @TomaszFałdrowicz Yes, Correct